# Importing an image to QGIS with no coordinates, only a scale of the drawing

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

Is it possible to import a drawining into QGIS without having any coordinates or CRS. The scale that I have is 1:1250.

Comment: Yes, you can import an image without any CRS or coordinates. When QGIS prompts you to choose a CRS, just specify non-earth. Of course, the image won't have any relationship with any real-world coordinates.